# Grub2 chainload syslinux

Tags: grub, iso, syslinux

I have a USB with GRUB installed.

I add linux ISO images, and use their `grub.cfg` file to boot. Everything fine so far, with many distros.

But now I want to boot an ISO image that doesn't have GRUB configuration, but SYSLINUX.

But I still haven't found what I'm looking for ;).

What I usually do is something like this:

```
set iso_file=/clonezilla-live-2.6.3-7-amd64.iso
loopback loop $iso_file

menuentry "Clonezilla live (Default settings, VGA 800x600)"{
  linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz ... findiso=$iso_file ...
  initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

But can't figure it out how to do something similar with SYSLINUX, if at all possible.

I would prefer not to exctract the files from the ISO.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to bypass the syslinux?

Comment: @jsotola I'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: insert a menu entry into grub that does the same thing that syslinux does

Comment: @jsotola *insert a menu entry into grub that does the same thing that syslinux does*. Thank you that solves the problem. I was focused on make the chainload and didn't think of that. Although would be nice to know if it can be done. Cheers.

Comment: try these two commands in a menuentry block ... `linux16 /memdisk iso` and `initrd16 clonezilla-live-2.6.3-7-amd64.iso` .... google "super grub disk"

Comment: IMO you should chainload the ISO file bootloader, not setting linux/initrd.